# Stereo camera calibration: system error

Tags: calibration, stereo, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to perform a calibration of a stereo usb camera using the usb_cam drivers. I am following the proper tutorial on the ROS wiki page (http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration).

My stereo camera is publishing left and right images over ROS (/image_raw), I can run the calibration node and I'm able to perform the acquisitions of the samples. When I push the "Calibrate" botton, not so long after it appears this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py", line 244, in on_mouse self.c.do_calibration()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 1052, in do_calibration self.cal_fromcorners(self.good_corners)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 855, in cal_fromcorners flags = flags)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

The roswtf command returns no errors or warnings.

I'm using ROS Indigo running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I just started using the ros framework so I'm not an expert at all.
The cameras I'm using are two ODROID USB-CAM 720P.
Can you please help me to figure out how to solve this isssue?

Greetings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213117/stereo-camera-calibration:-system-error/) by [I-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/23082/i-man/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-07-09**:
Hi! Make sure you are using the correct git branch, in case you compiled usb_cam repository from source.

**Comment by [I-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/23082/i-man/) on 2015-07-09**:
Thanks for your answer.
The git branch I'm using is correct. For the installation of usb_cam I followed the steps described in http://answers.ros.org/question/197651/how-to-install-a-driver-like-usb_cam/.

By the way I can perform the (mono) camera calibration successfully. What's wrong?

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-07-13**:
It looks like your opencv version is expecting a different set of arguments. Which version of OpenCV are you using? 2.4.11 is working correctly in my system. Are you on a newer version?

**Comment by [I-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/23082/i-man/) on 2015-07-13**:
Yes. the command pkg-config --modversion opencv returns 3.0.0. Should I use a previous version of OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

You should install a compatible OpenCV version, such as 2.4.11. That error is telling you that the code is not compatible, as the API has changed.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/23082/i-man/) on 2015-08-16**:
Thank you so much. As you suggested, I installed OpenCV 2.4.11 and it works!

**Comment by [Mudassir Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4582/mudassir-khan/) on 2016-01-16**:
I updated my openCV to 2.4.11 but still getting the same error. Any idea why ?